# Returning a variable gives undefined

Tags: node.js

```
let json = JSON.parse(body);
let assetname = JSON.stringify(json.Name);
return assetname;
```

In a function, I perform the above. It correctly gives me the JSON value, but when I return it to my main script, it becomes 'undefined'.

```
let name = await assetinfo(`${aid}`);
console.log(name)
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why do you use `await`? The function returns a string not a promise. Try `let name = assetinfo(aid);`

Comment: i get Promise { undefined }